# Splitting after pullback under finite flat morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, pullback

I recently became aware of an interesting result, which claims for smooth projective curve over a finite field, you can pull back any vector bundle, under combinations of Galois covers and Frobenius, so that it splits into direct sum of line bundles. I wasn't able to find the reference (I'd appreciate if anyone can provide the reference). You can find it [here](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Autumn/18.735/l_5.pdf), Theorem 5.5. I was wondering whether similar results are known in higher dimensions?

Comment: Thanks! I'll remove that part of question.

Comment: @ R. van Dobben de Bruyn After thinking about your argument, I'm a little bit skeptical. Is the Frob morphism also faithfully flat? In the paper linked above a short exact sequence is turned to a split one by the action of Frob.

Comment: Sorry I'm being dumb. Yes, Frobenius is faithfully flat (see also Kunz's theorem), but there is no flat base change happening. That would be if we did an extension of the ground field or something. Deleted my comment.

Comment: Here is a similar result for affine schemes (possibly singular and of arbitrary dimension), if we allow finite flat (possibly ramified) covers: Gabber, Liu, Lorenzini, [Hypersurfaces in projective schemes and a moving lemma](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1431608068), Proposition 6.10.

Comment: First of all, the proof breaks down because of complications with Chern classes, preventing one from reducing everything to dynamics of Frobenius on a fixed finite type moduli space. Second, I would be surprised if this was possible e.g. for the cotangent bundle on $\mathbf{P}^2$.